# Soldering solution for HDMI connector

Tags: soldering, hdmi

I have an HDMI connector that is clamped to the PCB, we are still hand soldering this position but often bridge or deflection occurs.
Can you give us any advice on how to auto solder this position?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does hand-soldering entail a soldering iron and solid solder, or a hot-air station and solder paste?

Comment: Also, I bet the manufacturer of the connector had some recommended procedure.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Of course, except for the hot-air, everything else is there.

Comment: They recommend by hand soldering but I wanted an improvement without using humans.

Comment: If you don't want to use humans, then you need an auto soldering machine i.e. robot (they exist).  The manufacturer of the machine will tell you how to use it.   How many of these are you making?  You gotta have a pretty good production run to make something like that worthwhile.  Or just outsource it to an assembly house and let them deal with it.

Comment: I suppose you could machine a fixture that both the PCB and connector nest into, and then use that for hand soldering. Probably of conductive teflon so it doesn't melt, static shock, or heatsink the parts.

Comment: @DKNguyen It might be possible to 3D print a fixture if the contact points were kept well away from the heat. At least it could act as a proof of concept.

Comment: Or drop the card edge connector for a right-angle through-hole/THR one. Whatever would suit your assembly contractor best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When soldering fine pitched parts by hand, we use as small a diameter solder as possible to prevent bridging of the solder. The small diameter prevents you from feeding the solder too quickly into the pad. 0.15 mm (6 thou) diameter solder is my go to solder for an application like this. Putting solder flux on the pads using a flux pen seems to make soldering easier.

A good soldering iron with a fine tip also helps, and will reduce the rate at which your hair turns gray. I prefer the Weller RT1 tip because it comes to a point like a pencil, and you get heat almost out to the end of the tip. A solder stencil, solder paste, and an air tool also works.

A jig helps with part alignment. It can be fancy like a machined part, or some wood and clamps. If a jig is too much work, solder one pin, check the alignment, and if it's off, reheat that pin and realign the connector. Once it's aligned properly, solder all the other pins. You can only do the reheat and realign a few times before the pad falls off.

When all else fails, send it to an assembly house.

Comment: *jigs guide a tool while fixtures hold the workpiece

Comment: Well noted, I will try.